# HTML Range Slider and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have the code below in my website and integrated a range slider using HTML5.  I want the slider to update the text-input with the value and vice versa.  Would I do this using jQuery?  If so can you give me example code?

Thanks.

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">

<input type="range" id="chance" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
```

Comment: ID should be unique to all elements.

Comment: ID's have to be unique, so you can't put 2 or more of the same id's on one page.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `change` event on slider and `keyup` event on textbox to update the values.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">

<input type="range" id="chanceSlider" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" step="0.01" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
```

jQuery

```
$('#chanceSlider').on('change', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
});

$('#chance').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#chanceSlider').val($('#chance').val());
});
```

And jsfiddle to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/tDkEW/1/

Comment: Note that on textbox with only `keyup` event hooked, if you copypaste with mouse only, it doesn't update the slider. To apply this functionality you should add `change` event to it too. Just to tell the logic behind this: `change` occurs when textbox loses focus and value has changed, `keyup` occurs every time when you release keyboard button.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refresh the value in real time use `mousemove`, or you can just use `change` but it's not at real time.

```
$('yourselector').on('mousemove change',function() { 
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Was looking everywhere for the real time update on this. Thanks.

Comment: thanks! was looking for this! it doesn't seem to work on touchscreens tho....

Answer (score 5):

An improvement I found useful

`$('#chanceSlider').on('input change', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#chanceSlider').val());
    });`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tDkEW/408/

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely use jQuery.

```
$('input#chance').on('change', function() { 
    $('input[name=chance]').val($(this).val()); 
});

$('input[name=chance]').on('change keyup', function() {
    $('input#chance').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with html5 elements and jQuery, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sRbHZ/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">
<input type="range" id="chance_slider" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
```

JS:

```
var slider = $('#chance_slider'),
    textbox = $('#chance');

slider.change(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).val());

    textbox.val(newValue);
});

textbox.change(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).val());

    slider.val(newValue);
});
```

**EDIT**

To allow decimals:

```
var slider = $('#chance_slider'),
    textbox = $('#chance');

slider.change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();

    textbox.val(newValue);
});

textbox.change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();

    slider.val(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much man.  But when I use that code, it doesn't allow decimals?

Comment: just remove `parseInt`: change `parseInt($(this).val());` to `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 0):

First Ids must be unique.You can use jQuery [**slider()**](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).You can use text box here to update that value in slider and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I suggest caching the jquery selectors to improve performance.
Also ids must be unique, see fiddle.

```
var $chance_txt = $('#chance_txt'),
    $chance_slider = $('#chance_slider').on('change', function() {
        $chance_txt.val($chance_slider.val());
    });
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3hnm/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Make your ids unique first.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="display" class="text" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider" class="vHorizon" min="0.01" max="98" style="background-color: #00aec8; width: 50%;">
```

JQuery

```
$('#slider').on('change',function(){
  $('#display').val($('#slider').val());
});
```