# The price bar with max and min prices

Tags: html

In some of the websites which make sales, there is a bar that you can set maximum and minimum price. I don't know technical name of it but i have a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

How can i do that with html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It won't be dynamic. I want to define min and max values and submit a search with a button. I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Have you considered using [jQuery UI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)?

Comment: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ seems to do the job (with some css and js).

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17482636/1699210)

Answer (score 5):

You can implement this pretty easily if you use something like jQuery UI assuming you have a little knowledge of Javascript. Here is an example of what you can achieve. https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

To see how it is implemented you can click 'View source' on that page or for quick reference I will leave it here.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
    $(function() {
     $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
     " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
   <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want an HTML version, you will need to look at the HTML5 sliders but browser support is limited. Here is a link if you would like some more information:

http://demosthenes.info/blog/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input

Comment: But i am afraid i don't have that javascript knowledge. Can you show on your answer how to use it with POST method form?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean how to POST the values recorded from the slider?

Comment: Yes i mean that. I want to use $_POST['min'] and $_POST['max'] at the search.

Comment: What you will need to do is have two hidden `<input type="hidden" name="min" id="minPrice" /><input type="hidden" name="max" id="maxPrice" />` and update them as you are sliding. A tip is that inside the `slide: function()` the `ui.values[0]` is the left slider and `ui.values[1]` is the right slider. This should be enough to at least get you thinking about what you need to be doing! If you have any more questions, just ask.

Answer (score 3):

Use two single sliders and render it as a double slider by hiding(use css and html).

```css
[slider] {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 45px 0 10px 0;
}

[slider] > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 5px;
}
[slider] > div > [inverse-left] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

[slider] > div > [inverse-right] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}


[slider] > div > [range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #d02128;
}

[slider] > div > [thumb] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
}

[slider] > input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 14px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -11px;
  top: -39px;
  z-index:3;
  background-color: #d02128;
  color: #fff;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

[slider] > div > [sign]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  top: 19px;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 16px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #d02128;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
}

[slider]:hover > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div slider id="slider-distance">
  <div>
    <div inverse-left style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div inverse-right style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div range style="left:0%;right:0%;"></div>
    <span thumb style="left:0%;"></span>
    <span thumb style="left:100%;"></span>
    <div sign style="left:0%;">
      <span id="value">0</span>
    </div>
    <div sign style="left:100%;">
      <span id="value">100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" value="0" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
  this.value=Math.min(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[5].value-1);
  let value = (this.value/parseInt(this.max))*100
  var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
  children[1].style.width=value+'%';
  children[5].style.left=value+'%';
  children[7].style.left=value+'%';children[11].style.left=value+'%';
  children[11].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />

  <input type="range" value="100" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
  this.value=Math.max(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[3].value-(-1));
  let value = (this.value/parseInt(this.max))*100
  var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
  children[3].style.width=(100-value)+'%';
  children[5].style.right=(100-value)+'%';
  children[9].style.left=value+'%';children[13].style.left=value+'%';
  children[13].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Its works for me.

**HTML**

```
    <input type="number" min="200" max="100" step="1" id="input-number">

    <input type="number" min="200" max="1000" step="1" id="input-number">
```

**JS**

```
var select = document.getElementById('input-select');
for ( var i = 200; i <= 1000; i++ ){
var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;
    option.value = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
var html5Slider = document.getElementById('html5');
noUiSlider.create(html5Slider, {
 start: [ 500, 800 ],
 connect: true,
 range: {
    'min': 200,
    'max': 1000
 }
});

var inputNumber = document.getElementById('input-number');

html5Slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

var value = values[handle];

if ( handle ) {
    inputNumber.value = value;
} else {
    select.value = Math.round(value);
}
});

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    html5Slider.noUiSlider.set([this.value, null]);
});

inputNumber.addEventListener('change', function(){
    html5Slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
});
```

Here is the live link:  https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/YeYpdr

Answer (score 1):

i read a tutorial it fits for you have a look

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 100, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    $( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
   }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
 " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

complete tutorial here if you have any problem http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/price-range-slider-using-jquery-css-and-php.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you have to support, maybe you can use the range from HTML5 :

```
<input type="range" min="10.50" max="50.00" step="0.50" />
```

You can also have a look at polyfills to support older browsers :

https://github.com/fryn/html5slider

https://github.com/freqdec/fd-slider

Comment: Actually i need 2 sliders in a range bar.