# input type range does not work inside angularjs repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have problem in input type range to get it's value on change method. The problem is it si working if ti is outside of the ng-repeate. I have search a lot but find any solution yet. I attached Plnkr file where you can see the code and all:
https://embed.plnkr.co/pEKXfPiR1tNHD4G2yDmU/

There ware soem example that I found, I am adding here for reference to solve this problem.
[HTML Range Slider and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482636/html-range-slider-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching your listeners before the DOM has been created. You need to use `document.ready()`

```
$(function() {
  $('#chanceSlider0').on('change', function() {
    $('#chance0').val( $('#chanceSlider0').val() );
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/857cFkfwf48ZTNJ8PWHX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix jquery and angularjs which is not a good thing and is not recommended. 
i would suggest you have a look at

https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider